# I need to make a loop wait for a set amount of time before iterating to the next loop

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine

The current code I have is crashing the game completely:

```
public void fire(float angle)
{
    int burst = 0;
    bool waitActice = false;

    while(burst < 3){
            if (waitActive == false) {

                    Debug.Log("Created " + burst + " burst");
                    StartCoroutine (wait (5f));
                    Debug.Log ("done waiting");
                    burst++;
            }
    }
}

IEnumerator wait(float time)
{
    Debug.Log ("Now waiting");
    waitActive = true;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    waitActive = false;
}
```

I have attempted the same thing with a for loop, but the for loop would continue to iterate until it was all complete. I want to create 3 bursts with 5 seconds between each burst, but when the fire function is called it crashes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that you have a waitActive as a field in your class, but you hide it with your local bool waitActice = false;.

I guess this because your wait refers to waitActive.

You could try this:

```
public IEnumerator fire(float angle)
{
    int burst = 0;

    while(burst < 3){
        Debug.Log("Created " + burst + " burst");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
        Debug.Log ("done waiting");
        burst++;
    }
}
```

Then do

```
StartCoroutine(fire(9.2));
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to complete what was required of me with this help.

Answer (score 1):

Why not thread.sleep ?

```
      Thread thread = new Thread(() => fire(angle)); // this will execute your method in a new thread.
      thread.Start();



public void fire(float angle)
         {
          int burst = 0;
          bool waitActice = false;

          while(burst < 3){
          if (waitActive == false) {
                Thread.Sleep(5000); // will wait for 5 seconds
                Debug.Log("Created " + burst + " burst");
                StartCoroutine (wait (5f));
                Debug.Log ("done waiting");
                burst++;
          }
        }
     }
```

Comment: I have attempted that, but unfortuantely that stops the whole thing from funtioning, there are other areas of this that still need to operate. Sorry I should have mentioned this.

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable `LastFireTime`.

Set it to 0, 
Keep incrementing it in the update function.

```
LastFireTime += Time.deltaTime;
```

that way you know how much time since the last fire and you can reset it to 0 every time you fire again.

Do not wait as the game update function must return ASAP